# IBM Heap Analyzer - finalize method

Tags: java, performance, finalizer, heap-dump

The following screenshow is taken from IBM Heap Analyzer.
[image]

I want to understand the difference between 'Number of Objects with Finalize() method' and 'Number of garbage objects implementing finalize() method'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, "Number of Objects with Finalize() method" means there are 5 live objects on the heap which have a finalize method. If you have many of those, then they don't do any harm as such - until they have to be GC'd. So it's a hint of something brewing on the horizon.

The value "Number of garbage objects implementing finalize() method" says how many objects have been garbage collected that do have a `finalize()` method. Unlike the number above, these are objects which have paid the price.

If the first number is small and those objects are long lived, there is no need to worry.

If the first number is small and the second number is high, that means you have many short lived objects with a `finalize()` method and this could be a problem because it makes GC runs more expensive.